# Modify a Gravity Form button with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, gravityforms

I don't find how to convert the gravity form button "previous" to another word "jump back".
Does someone can give me a tip?

add_filter( 'gform_previous_button_13', 'previous', 10, 2 );

I don't find the filter to add another word instead.

Comment: the documentation
https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_previous_button/#examples

Comment: This should be something that you can specify in the settings.  [See Here](https://docs.gravityforms.com/page-break/).  When you get to the end, there's a spot for the text on the Previous button.

Comment: Thank you you're great !

Answer (score 1):

Try following code please:

```
add_filter( 'gform_submit_button', 'custom_previous_button', 10, 2 );
function custom_previous_button( $button, $form ) {
return "<button class='button gform_next_button' id='gform_next_button_{$form['id']}'><span>Previous</span></button>";
```

}

Reference: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_previous_button/#examples